# How to run DBT model and pass a variable at run time

Tags: dbt

We have a DBT application which we run in pods using Apache Airflow in AWS. I have a model which I need to run for a specific appId. I need to pass the parameter appId at runtime in cli command to the DBT model so that the model runs only for that specific appId.

We run the following DBT command to run a model on our local machine.

```
dbt -d run --model abc
```

The Apache airflow code that we use to run DBT model is :

```
abc_task = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                  image=f'blotout/dbt-analytics:{TAG_DBT_ANALYTICS}',
                                  cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                  arguments=['run', '--models', 'abc_task'],
                                  env_vars=env_var,
                                  name="abc_task",
                                  configmaps=['awskey'],
                                  task_id="abc_task",
                                  get_logs=True,
                                  dag=dag,
                                  is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                  )
```

We need something like this:

```
{%- set appIdList = ['{{ var("appId") }}'] -%}
```

And the value of appId should be passed through Airflow task as shown above in the CLI command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using environment variables to share the information from your Apache Airflow DAG with the Kubernetes Pod running dbt?

In your case, you could declare `APP_ID` within the `env_vars` dictionary.

Inside the dbt model file, you can use the `env_var` function to incorporate environment variables from the system into the model using Jinja:

```
{{ env_var('APP_ID') }}
```

The dbt docs give more details about this feature:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var

Answer (score 1):

[Project variables](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/project-variables) offer this functionality. They can be defined either in  `dbt_project.yml` or [on the command line](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/project-variables#defining-variables-on-the-command-line).

The model should use this variable in order to limit execution for the specific use case.

Here's an example of how this is possible with by adding `--vars` in `KubernetesPodOperator` arguments for dbt:

```
abc_task = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                  image=f'blotout/dbt-analytics:{TAG_DBT_ANALYTICS}',
                                  cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                  arguments=['run', '--models', 'abc_task', '--vars', '{"appId": "id-123"}'],
                                  env_vars=env_var,
                                  name="abc_task",
                                  configmaps=['awskey'],
                                  task_id="abc_task",
                                  get_logs=True,
                                  dag=dag,
                                  is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                  )
```

Comment: Could you share the code snippet or the command for this?

Comment: Edited the answer to provide an example using `KubernetesPodOperator`.